Related to Laplace Transform and Expectation operator
in my research work I came across the following expression:
$P_1 = \mathbb{E}_{I}\bigl[\exp(-\tau\cdot f\cdot I)\bigr]$---(1)
where $f,\tau$ are constant and $I$ is random variable.
$P_2 = \mathcal{L}_{I}(\tau\cdot f)$---(2)
where $\mathcal{L}_I(.)$ is Laplace transform
My query is how equation (2) is obtained from equation (1). Especially how $I$ and negative sign is omitted in eq. (2).
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Why do you think $P_2$ is obtained from $P_1$? I just see two independent definitions.

Thank u sir for ur response.... I think $P_2$ is obtained from $P_1$ because in the equations which I am referring, $P_2$ was written on the basis of $P_1$....

If $I$ is non-negative, the you can just view $P_1$ as the definition of the Laplace transform (which has a $-$ sign in the exponent in it's definition)

Ok Thank u so much sir for your reply...Got the point....
